# An fault occurs in demo of HUOBI API

Tags: php, account

Thank you for viewing.
I am an engineer in Japan.
I am glad that you can understand that you are not very good at English.

Well, it is the main subject.

Programming language is PHP.
I am trying to obtain account information by using HUOBI's API.

https://github.com/huobiapi/REST-API-demos/tree/master/REST-PHP-DEMO

An error occurred when `get_balance()` was executed by changing the setting of `demo.php` to my ID and password.

The details of the error are as follows.

```
object(stdClass)#2 (4) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(5) "error"
  ["err-code"]=>
  string(44) "account-get-balance-account-inexistent-error"
  ["err-msg"]=>
  string(64) "account for id `*,***,***` and user id `×,×××,×××` is not exist"
  ["data"]=>
  NULL
}
```

`*,***,***` is my UID!!
`×,×××,×××` id Next number of UID（UID＋1）

Source is exactly as git goes up.
I will wait for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i just wan't that somebody be able to google it because huobi support refuses to confirm or fix the problem.
If you're getting "account-frozen-account-inexistent-error" while placing new  it's possible, that everything is ok with your account, but you have no funds for concrete asset. For example, you have 0 BTC and trying to sell some BTC to exchange them with USDT. You'll get this error instead of "insufficient balance" or something more appropriate

Comment: Yep, same for me

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

you got the error message "account-get-balance-account-inexistent-error"

which means your account is not correct in define.
Please make sure you've define the value beforehand.

```
define('ACCOUNT_ID', ''); 
define('ACCESS_KEY',''); 
define('SECRET_KEY', '');
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
define has already defined its own number.

Comment: as long as you got the error code, which means the connection between the SDK and the service is normal. the rest of the error code has nothing to do with the programming language. You should refer to the official API documentation of the service you're trying to use.

Comment: I can not solve the problem by reading official document and using official demo.

It certainly may not be related to the program.
For example UID is not effective without doing some procedure. . . . .

Comment: You should logon to the panel to make sure the account ID is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. Of course I'm logging in with my account and checking that the UID and KEY match.

Comment: I suggest you to use the official SDK instead, since the endpoint requirements might be change from time to time.

Comment: Problem solved.
API can not be used for UID obtained by logging in.
By using the account ID displayed on the endpoint "/account / "
Private API is available.
We appreciate Wils who responded!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Check your UID here:https://www.huobi.com/en-us/user_center/uc_info/
then get your **account-id** here [get account-id](https://github.com/huobiapi/API_Docs_en/wiki/REST_Reference#get-v1accountaccounts-get-all-the-accounts-pro-and-hadax-share-the-same-account-id)

Replace `XXXXXXX` in `define('ACCOUNT_ID', 'XXXXXXX')` by your **account-id**

Happy show hand :)